# Rstudio does not open or is terribly slow

Tags: r, performance, rstudio

When I open RStudio, sometimes I get the error page and need to retry many times (after having launched Rgui) before to be able to access it.
Furthermore, once RStudio starts, it is terribly slow. The first 5 minutes I just have an empty screen [see attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOOQa.png)
I can't create a new project (I click on file-new project but nothing happens) and I can't even run easy codes (just tried 3+4 and it took 2 minutes to give me the result).
I tried to create a new project (took 5 minutes) but it still gives me the same problem.

I have reinstalled it yesterday and it was working fine.
R and RStudio versions are the latest, Windows 10

Comment: I confirm, it is a speed issue. If I wait ~10 minutes, it starts to work, although very slowly. It took 4 minutes to load ggplot and 2 minutes to create a simple graph  (below)

ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_point(mapping= aes(x=displ, y=cyl))

Comment: what error do you get? also what is the ram usage while starting rstudio? what does working fine after reinstalling it mean? is rgui working fine without rstudio?

Comment: I do not get any specific error, it just takes year to do whatever (from just launching RStudio do stupid 1+3 math and so on). RAM usage is 60% (5/8 GB). Working fine means that I had no problem in plotting or doing maths, as well as in creating new projects etc. Yes,  rgui seems to work fine

Comment: did you try this: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-running-abnormally-slow-for-every-action-including-cleaning-console-and-saving-file/24878/8

Comment: Yes, did not work at all :/

Comment: Just got the message "r session aborted fatal error" while I was reading "?labs"

Comment: what happens if you install an older version of Rstudio?

Comment: I had to upload it to use latest version of packages such as ggplot2